# Class not defined when I instantiate it within a function

Tags: python, function, class, methods

When I want to instantiate a class in a function, it says that the class is not defined.

error:

```
NameError: name 'bataljon' is not defined
```

code:

```
class GameClass:

  ------------------------------------#def __init__ is here but it doesn't matter now

    #kar se samo ko se vzge igra naredi

  class bataljon:
    def __init__(self, bataljon_army_size, bataljon_power, bataljon_pos_x, bataljon_pos_y):
      self.bataljon_army_size = bataljon_army_size
      self.bataljon_power = bataljon_power
      self.bataljon_pos_x = bataljon_pos_x
      self.bataljon_pos_y = bataljon_pos_y
      self.have_destination = False

    def bataljon_function(self):
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (player_color), (bataljon_pos_x, bataljon_pos_y, 100, 100))

    

  def game_script(self):

   -------------------------------------------#mouse input that doesn't matter


    #Input
    for event in self.pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == self.QUIT:
        self.pygame.quit()
        self.sys.exit()


   -----------------------------------------#mouse input that doesn't matter



    #Keyboard
      if event.type == self.pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 
        if event.key == self.pygame.K_q:
          a = bataljon(1000, 0, self.mouse_position_x, self.mouse_position_x)

    ----------------------------------#drawing on screen which doesn't matter
```

Previously I had the class bataljon in the _ *init* _ method and moved it out but it still doesn't work.

Goodbye!

Comment: `GameClass.bataljon`

Comment: You need to use: `a = GameClass.bataljon(...)`